# Rails ActiveRecord: selecting and sorting on a dynamic field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models, one is Group, the other Item.

A group has many items.

I'm trying to run a query on groups, and return the number of items for each group as a method of the group object.

The view should be  :

```
<% @groups.each do |group| %>
   <tr><td><%= group.name %></td><td><%= group.items_count %></td> ... and other fields
<% end %>
```

I'd like to be able to do a Group.where().page call including the dynamic attribute items_count, and be able to sort results by item_count, just as a standard attribute from the sql table. how can I do that in a simple way ?

Comment: Have you looked in to doing a scope? There's also some good information [here](http://www.railway.at/2010/03/09/named-scopes-are-dead/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to fetch the groups you need without a specific ordering, and then sort them in your controller afterwards:

```
def my_action
  @groups = Group.all()  # or Group.where(...) for more specific filtering
  @groups.sort! { |g1, g2| g1.items_count <=> g2.items_count }
  ...
end
```

Comment: I was hoping to be able to do : @groups.all.sort(params[:sort_by]) where sort_by contains 'items_count', or 'group_name', etc.